# How can I move my Swift-based iOS apps to Flutter?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I have five iOS apps available in AppStore, written in Swift, XCode. Currently I am working on Flutter and would like to launch my apps in both AppStore and Google Store.

**My goal is to create a new version and publish an update (for iOS), with same Bundle IDs, so current users won't recognize the code changes and when smoothly updates their apps, they get the final versions.**

Despite searching flutter.dev and stackoverflow, I haven't been able to find the right answer yet.

I appreciate if someone can provide a step-by-step guide on how to manage this problem.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Are you asking about whether there is a tool to take a swift app and convert it to Flutter? Answer: No. Are you asking how to release a re-written app as an update? Answer: Just use the same app-is and certs. (Ps: personal opinion: hybrid suck, stay native)

Comment: Yes, I am asking for the second case. So you mean if I use the same bundleID, everything will be fine. (ps: Flutter seems more than hybrid, just check in detail please)

Comment: Yes an update is merely another app with the same bundle name. You can test this, install your current app on your phone, create a hello world flutter app with the same bundle ID and the second will overwrite the first. Re: hybrid, its still referred to as Hybrid even if it compiles down to native code at the end. Whether you call it hybrid or cross platform or something else, they all have massive downsides in exchange for the convenience and there is a new favourite every week

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin well what are your downsides on flutter comparing to native development?

Comment: @J.Doe same as all cross platform tools. In order to achieve this, a default native project with a lot of libraries is created, and then code is piled on top. This setup adds a lot of overhead for resources and app size. Last company I worked for started building features in React-Native. It doubled the app download size and the app is now exceeding the limit apple allows for apps to be downloaded over 3G. App now can't be downloaded on the move and made some of their advertising pointless. Dev rant uses Appcelerators titanium and burns battery like theres no tomorrow, so does Facebook.

Comment: One of the number one complaints from mobile users is when an Android app looks too much like an iPhone app or vice versa. Having "one UI across all platforms" is something businesses want to save time, its not what customers want. These tools are all brand new and haven't been tested as throughly as the native tools, any time you save in development will be returned 10 fold in trying to debug and solve bizarre issues that nobody has ever faced.

Comment: The community size will be a tiny fraction of the native meaning you'll have less support. A new one is released constantly, everybody moves over and all the same issues start again ... to name a few. You don't get "write once deploy anywhere" without some kind of trade off. I don't believe its the right call for the customer to have to suffer with poor battery life and big app downloads so save a little dev time (which is in fact rarely the case)

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin I very appreciate your answer! Buddy of mine is praising OutSystems, but I already thought that is nonsense... Thanks, I keep this in mind :)

Comment: @J.Doe I've never even heard of OutSystems and had to go google it. This is in itself part of the problem, yet another new player on the field, making all the same mistakes. They even copied titanium and have their own marketplace for pre-built modules custom to their platform. Not interested.

Answer (score 1):

There is no instant way to convert it, but you can use

[Flutter Method Channel](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)

Buy using

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  // Android-specific code
} else if (Platform.isIOS) {
  // iOS-specific code
}
```

you can specify if if the current feature only available on that platform.

By using same package name and same app signing it will replace the current app on the store, and user can update it

1.[Build And Release Android App](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android)

2.[Build And Release IOS App](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/ios)